# Problem adding a new section?

Tags: sectioning

I think my question is pretty simple, but since I've been using LaTex for 2 days by now... Anyway, the thing is I'm having a problem adding a new section. I use the command `\section`, but in the previous section there is three subsections, the last one is filled up with lots of images and when I input a new section, the section begins right after the first image of the previous subsection and I don't know how to solve it.

End of the code:

```
%last picture of the subsection%

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{28_google}
    \caption{$\sqrt[3]{28}$ \hspace{0.5mm} calculated by Google with 11 places of precision and 11 places after the comma.}
    \label{fig:28_google}
\end{figure}

\section {Conclusions}
```

This section appears after the first image instead of the end of the subsection. If anyone could help, thank you!

PS: I want the fourth section to start after the previous subsection (the one with images).

Comment: hard to say without an example but `\clearpage\section{zzz}` will force a new page and flush all floating images before starting the next section

Comment: also don't use `[h]` it usually generates a warning that latex is changing it ht but even then it makes it very likely the figure floats to the end of the document, use no optional argument or always include `p` so `[htp]`

Comment: Thank you David! the \clearpage\section{zzz} worked just fine :) and also thanks for the tip about the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 \clearpage\section{zzz}
```

will force a new page and flush all floating images before starting the next section

Answer (score 2):

use

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
```

With `!` it will ignore the restriction for placing floats